# Views/Widgets are not wrapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I will just cut to the chase and paste all of my xml for a particular Activity below. The problem I'm having is that the widgets are not wrapping, and so much of the text is bleeding off the right edge of the screen.

As I'm using "wrap_content" for the width, I don't understand why this is happening.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSendLocWhenItChanges"
            android:text="Send My Pterodactyl When It Changes"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxSendToSelectedDuckbilledPlatypiWhenPterodactylChanges"
            android:text="Send My Pterodactyl to Selected Duckbilled Platypi When It Changes" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSendOnPterodactylChangedToSelected"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Select Recipients From Contacts" />

        <TextView android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Send Pterodactyl to selected Duckbilled Platypi from Contact List when my Pterodactyl changes by more than the following number of miles:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextMilesBeforeNotification"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView android:layout_height="10px" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView android:layout_height="20px" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewBuildStringOfWhoReceivesChangeOfPterodactylUpdates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Pterodactyl will be immediately sent to "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView android:layout_height="40px" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNext"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save and Exit Keep In Touch Configuration" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

layout_width does not apply to TableRows. Use layout_span when you have a single column spanning two columns. Try using android:shrinkColumns. Hope it helps.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that layout_height also does not work with TableRows?

Comment: layout_height is always WRAP_CONTENT http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html